# Generic type instantiation using reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Assuming the following data model:

```
public Test extends CanDeserialize {
   private List<String> userRoles; 
   ...
}
```

When requiring to deserialize the object manually and having to instantiate an object for the `userRole`, the following problems happen:

1. Java reflection recognizes `List<String>` as `List` when calling the `.GetType()` method
2. When calling `.GetGenericType()` method, the actual type of `T` cannot be instantiated, as the method does not provide any function for that purpose.
3. Extracting the type from inside the `<>` and instantiating through `Class.fromClass(...)` may cause problems as the generic type maybe very complex, for example `Pair<Pair<String,int>, Pair<String,int>>`

Assuming that deserialization takes place inside of the class as follows:

```
public abstract CanDeserialize{
    public void deserialize(String object){
        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    }
```

How can I instantiate an object for the `userRoles`??

Comment: Didn't you just ask this same question about 2 hours ago? Or am I confused?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: You are surly confused :D (no disrespect :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java you can do the following:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("Some Values");
```

Now assuming you have a `List<String>` you can set value using reflection through getting fields (as you did) and then

```
fields[0].set(this, list); // in your example there's 1 field only, so the index is 0.
```

This works because in Java, any generics eventually lead to `Object` type. And yeah that means you don't need reflection to initialize that.